# How to redirect the Index of / to a website?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I made a VirtualHost to access to a php file and I want to allow access to this page and files in `folder1`.
Here are my folders :

```
root
|mywebsite.php
|.htaccess
|otherfiles
|
|--images
|  |image.jgp
|
|--style
|  |style.css
|
|--folder1
|  |a_lot_of_folders
```

I can deny the access to the otherfiles in the root directory. If the URL is : `www.ipaddress/` or `www.ipaddress/otherfiles` it will redirect to `www.ipaddress/mywebsite.php`.
But what I want is allow access only to the php file and files in `folder1`. But if the URL looks like this : `www.ipaddress/folder1` or this : `www.ipaddress/style` it will open the `Index of /folder` and I don't want this.

Here is my .htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^$ mywebsite.php
RewriteRule ^otherfiles$ mywebsite.php # This is for each files in the root folder except the php one
RewriteRule ^/folder1? mywebsite.php # This doesn't work
```

I tried to rewrite the URL when it has `/folder1` but it does nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this as your last rules:

```sh
RewriteRule ^folder1/?$ mywebsite.php [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^folder1/ mywebsite.php [L,NC]
```

Comment: Is REQUEST_FILENAME something I should change or just write it as you did ?

Comment: Well it changed nothing :/

Comment: What URL did you  enter in browser to test this and what error did you get?

Comment: I tried `ipaddress/folder1` and it still opens the Index of /folder so I get no error

Comment: You should probably leave out the rule with the -d that checks if a directory doesn't exist. You want to rewrite everything except for existing files to the mywebsite.php

Comment: Oh it works (Without the !-d line) ! Thanks alot, I just have a little problem, the website doesn't load the image, does it comes from the fact the image has it's own folder ? Or the browser cache maybe ?

Comment: That is because you are using relative links for css/images. You can add this just below `<head>` tag of your page's HTML: `<base href="/" />`.

Comment: @anubhava You should edit your anwser, for me it works without this line `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` and the last one doesn't have a dor after folder1 : `RewriteRule ^folder1/ mywebsite.php [L,NC]`